# Formatar número de Celular em TextView - android

Tags: java, android

Tenho um `TextView` que exibe o número do telefone do usuário, gostaria de exibir na minha aplicação uma mascara que deixasse o número do celular  no formato `(xx) xxxx-xxxxx`. Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Ola Mateus, você esta usando algum Framework para o desenvolvimento? Phonegap ou outro? Java Puro? Coloque um trecho do seu código para sabermos pelo menos como é este seu textView.

Comment: @PauloRoberto editei a pergunta com mais informações.

Comment: Um Jquery ou JavaScript te ajudaria neste caso? Ou teria que ser algo em java mesmo?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, você tem um número sem formato nenhum e quer de alguma forma exibir este número em um `TextView` com o formato determinado, é isso? Quando você diz "máscara", eu entendo que seja em um `EditText`, para que no momento que o usuário vai digitando, o formato seja aplicado.

Comment: Exato @PauloRodrigues, realmente mask remete a EditText, alterei a pergunta.

Comment: @PauloRoberto tem que ser java mesmo

Comment: O número está disponível de que forma para você? Como três inteiros ou um long? Ou string?

Answer (score 2):

Considerando que o número está em um `long`, você pode usar `String.format()`:

```
long telefone = 55123456789L; // (55) 1234-56789
// (xx) xxxx-xxxxx
String s = String.format("(%02d) %04d-%05d",
   (telefone / 1000000000L) % 100, (telefone / 10000) % 10000, telefone % 100000);
textView.setText(s);
```

As divisões retiram a parte direita do número enquanto o resto retira a parte esquerda do `long`. Eu usei `long` pois o `int` não tem bits o suficiente para 11 dígitos do número.

Se o número estiver disponível em três inteiros, então você pode usar:

```
// (xx) xxxx-xxxxx
// (99) 1234-56789
int codigo = 99;
int esquerda = 1234;
int direita = 56789;

String s = String.format("(%02d) %04d-%05d", codigo, esquerda, direita);
textView.setText(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu constumo fazer assim:

Tenho os métodos estáticos na minha classe PhoneMaskController, que limpam e adicionam a formatação:

```
public static String clearFormating(String phoneNumber) {
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("-", "")
            .replace(" ", "");
    return phoneNumber;
}

public static String formatPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (phoneNumber.length() >= 5 && phoneNumber.length() < 9) {
        sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(0, 4));
        sb.append('-');
        sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(4, phoneNumber.length()));
    } else if (phoneNumber.length() == 9) {

        sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(0, 5));
        sb.append('-');
        sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(5, phoneNumber.length()));

    } else if (phoneNumber.length() == 10) {

        sb.append("(");
        sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(0, 2));
        sb.append(") ");
        sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(2, 6));
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(6, phoneNumber.length()));

    } else if (phoneNumber.length() == 11) {
        if (phoneNumber.startsWith("0")) {
            sb.append("(");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(0, 3));
            sb.append(") ");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(3, 7));
            sb.append("-");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(7, phoneNumber.length()));

        } else {
            sb.append("(");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(0, 2));
            sb.append(") ");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(2, 7));
            sb.append("-");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(7, phoneNumber.length()));
        }

    } else if (phoneNumber.length() == 12) {
        if (phoneNumber.startsWith("0")) {
            sb.append("(");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(0, 3));
            sb.append(") ");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(3, 8));
            sb.append("-");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(8, phoneNumber.length()));

        } else {
            sb.append("(");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(0, 2));
            sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(2, 4));
            sb.append(") ");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(4, 8));
            sb.append("-");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(8, phoneNumber.length()));
        }

    } else if (phoneNumber.length() == 13) {
        if (phoneNumber.startsWith("0")) {
            sb.append("(");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(0, 3));
            sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(3, 5));
            sb.append(") ");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(5, 9));
            sb.append("-");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(9, phoneNumber.length()));
        } else {
            sb.append("(");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(0, 2));
            sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(2, 4));
            sb.append(") ");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(4, 9));
            sb.append("-");
            sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(9, phoneNumber.length()));
        }

    } else if (phoneNumber.length() == 14) {
        sb.append("(");
        sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(0, 3));
        sb.append(" ");
        sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(3, 5));
        sb.append(") ");
        sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(5, 10));
        sb.append("-");
        sb.append(phoneNumber.subSequence(10, phoneNumber.length()));

    } else {
        sb.append(phoneNumber);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

No meu fragment e/ou activity que estiver trabalhando com o edittext, adiciono o seguinte parametro no edittext:

```
yourEdittext.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcherPhoneNumber);
```

E o seguinte método:

```
 private TextWatcher filterTextWatcherPhoneNumber = new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            try {
                if (isUpdatingNumber) {
                    isUpdatingNumber = false;
                    return;
                }

                String result = PhoneMaskController.clearFormating(s.toString());
                if (result.length() < 15) {
                    result = PhoneMaskController.formatPhoneNumber(result);
                } else {
                    result = result.substring(0, 15);
                    result = PhoneMaskController.formatPhoneNumber(result);
                }
                isUpdatingNumber = true;
                itemUserPhone.setText(result);
                itemUserPhone
                        .setSelection(itemUserPhone.getText().length());
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score -2):

Para quem precisar, criei esse método de formatação de telefone / mascara de telefone que fica no formato (xx) x xxxx-xxxx ou (xx) xxxx-xxxx

```
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.widget.EditText

class FormataTelefone(private val editText: EditText) : TextWatcher {

    private var isFormatting: Boolean = false
    private var deletedDigit: Boolean = false

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        deletedDigit = count > after
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

    override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
        if (isFormatting) {
            return
        }

        isFormatting = true

        val digits = editable.toString().replace("[^\\d]".toRegex(), "")
        val formatted = StringBuilder()

        if (digits.length == 1) {
            formatted.append("(${digits}")
        } else if (digits.length == 2) {
            formatted.append("(${digits}")
        } else if (digits.length in 3..6) {
            formatted.append("(${digits.substring(0,2)}) ${digits.substring(2,digits.length)}")
        } else if (digits.length in 7..10) {
            formatted.append("(${digits.substring(0,2)}) ${digits.substring(2,6)}-${digits.substring(6,digits.length)}")
        } else if (digits.length == 11) {
            formatted.append("(${digits.substring(0,2)}) ${digits.substring(2,3)} ${digits.substring(3,7)}-${digits.substring(7,digits.length)}")
        } else if (digits.length > 11) {
            formatted.append("(${digits.substring(0,2)}) ${digits.substring(2,3)} ${digits.substring(3,7)}-${digits.substring(7,11)}")
        }

        editText.setText(formatted.toString())
        editText.setSelection(formatted.length.coerceAtMost(16))

        isFormatting = false
    }
}
```

Na Activity dentro do onCreate inserir

```
    // Mascara do Telefone
    val tel = binding.edtTelefone
    tel.addTextChangedListener(FormataTelefone(tel))
```